# Exclude some ids from result in Rails ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have following statement for query articles from some sections

```
Article.all(:joins => :sections, :conditions => { :sections =>{ :id => [3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9] }, :id_not_in => @some_ids  }, :limit => 4)
```

Variable @some_ids is array with ids of articles which must be excluded from result.

Comment: What is your question exactly??

Comment: what's the relation between articles and sections?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If `Article` `has_many :sections`, try:

```
Article.find(:all, :joins => :sections, :conditions => ["sections.id IN (?) AND
   id NOT IN (?)", [1,2,3], @some_ids], :limit => 4)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Article.all(:joins => :sections, 
  :conditions => [ 'sections.id in ? and sections.id not in ?', 
  [3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9], @some_ids ], :limit => 4)
```

*untested*