# How to retrieve and exclude some ids from an ActiveRecord query?

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a User object, and an Alliance object, where User has_many :alliances, and Alliance belongs_to :user.  I want to get a list of users, but exclude those users with whom the current_user already has an active alliance (if the user already has an alliance, the :pending field will be false).

Here's a concrete example.  Suppose our users are Joe, Bob and Jill.  Joe and Jill are active allies, so Joe.alliances will include Jill, and Jill,alliances will include Joe.  I want a list of all users that exclude alliances for the current user, so if Joe is current_user, then I want an array of User objects that does not include Jill, but does include Bob.

In code, what I have so far:

```
# Get all users
user_list = User.all

# Get alliances that are not pending
active_alliances = current_user.where(:pending => false)
```

Now, I was thinking of using [this tip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580980/exclude-some-ids-from-result-in-rails-activerecord) to exclude from user_list the active_alliances.  So, what I need to do is extract from active_alliances a single-dimensional array with nothing other than a list of user_ids.  I'm thinking something like:

```
# Select just the :ally field (which contains the user_id of the ally)
alliance_id_list = current_user.all(:select => "ally")
```

This last isn't quite what I want, because it gives me a hash.  Now, I could just iterate through the hash, but I'm thinking that might not be the best way.  Is there a direct method to do this?  Perhaps by setting a negative conditional for the query?  Thanks.

**Update:** See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581376/how-to-exclude-an-array-of-ids-from-query-in-rails-using-activerecord) for more details on how to solve this problem; it can be used in connexion with the .collect method suggested below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I'm reading your question correctly, but it looks like you just need to collect the alliance user ids:

```
User.where("ally not in ?", current_user.alliances.collect(&:user_id))
```

Comment: Using the .collect method gets me closer to a solution.  I see now, though, that the question isn't very clear and I'll try to work up a  clearer question.  Thank you for the suggestion.