# Rails how to get table results with a join on itself?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following `Activity` table:

```
ID      TYPE        SKU
=======================
1       create      ABC
2       create      DEF
3       destroy     DEF
```

**How can I get all *`create`* events which DON'T have a *`destroy`* event?**

Doing `Activity.where(type: 'create')` gives me ids 1 and 2.

But I only want the first row since id 2 also has a destroy event.

Comment: Unless you are doing STI, using Type as a column name is not recommended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this should work

```
Activity.where('activities.type = ? AND activities.sku NOT IN
  (SELECT sku from activities where type = ?)', 'create', 'destroy')
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a rails way of doing this as well?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581376/how-to-exclude-an-array-of-ids-from-query-in-rails-using-activerecord

Comment: This still gives back activities which have a 'destroy' record.

Comment: Ahh, had to change the id to sku.... `Activity.where('activities.type = ? AND activities.sku NOT IN (SELECT sku from activities where type = ?)', 'create', 'destroy')`

Answer (score 1):

IF you really want to use active record, this gets you closer:

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :with_destroy, lambda { where(:action => 'destroy') }
  scope :create, lambda {where(:action => 'create') }

  scope :create_without_destroy, lambda {
    create.where("sku not in (" << Activity.select(:sku).with_destroy.group(:sku).to_sql << ")")
  }

end
```

The generated SQL:

```
> Activity.create_without_destroy
SELECT "activities".* FROM "activities" 
WHERE "activities"."action" = 'create' AND (
  sku not in (
  SELECT 
    sku 
  FROM "activities" 
  WHERE "activities"."action" = 'destroy' 
  GROUP BY sku
))
```

Comment: That's awesome. But the active record way seems like it would be hard for other devs to make sense of later.

Comment: Yes, I'd go with just the straight SQL, but you asked for a more "rails" way.